# SQL copy and paste table data into that same table by only changing one value

Tags: sql, sql-server, primary-key, on-duplicate-key

I want to copy and paste table data into that same table by only changing one value

Example: BillingLocationID

It's not possible to do it one by one inserting there are large number of rows.

I've created a #temptable and changed the value that I wanted to change

```
select *
into #temptablepop
from Productlocation
where BillingLocationID = 1
and DepartmentID = 3

update #temptablepop set BillingLocationID = '3'

insert into ProductLocation
select * from #temptablepop
```

and this gives me an error

> An explicit value for the identity column in table 'ProductLocation' can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON.

So I tried

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT Productlocation ON
```

Then I'm getting this

> An explicit value for the identity column in table 'ProductLocation' can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON

Then I tried this method

```
INSERT Into tableA ([c1], [c2], [c3], [c4], [c5] ) 
SELECT [c1], [c2], [c3], [c4], [c5] FROM tableB
```

And still it gives me this

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_dbo.ProductLocation'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.ProductLocation'. The duplicate key value is (4284).

Is there any other way?

Comment: Copy/paste is a user-interface concept, not a SQL concept. Please search this site for `[sql-server] Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint.`. There are several hundred existing questions and answers that should help you resolve this issue.

Comment: You're inserting new values, so of course they are going to clash with existing values. It seems you want an `UPDATE` statement, or otherwise you need to delete the data from your table before inserting new data. Note you should always specify the columns you are inserting into (you don't when inserting from your temp table).

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Please either ask re 1 bad query/function with obligatory [mre], including why you think it should return something else or are unsure at the 1st subexpression that you get what you expect or are stuck, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do with justification & a [mre--then misunderstood code doesn't belong. But please ask about unexpected behaviour 1st because misconceptions get in the way of your goal. [ask] [Help] Basic questions are faqs.

Comment: Please before considering posting: Pin down code issues via [mre]. Read manuals/references & google error messages & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. SO/SE search is poor & literal & unusual, read the help. Google re googling/searching, including Q&A at [meta] & [meta.se]. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help] Reflect research in posts.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't specify the Id.

Just do this:

```
INSERT Into tableA ([c2], [c3], [c4], [c5], [BillingLocationID]) 
SELECT [c2], [c3], [c4], [c5], '3' [BillingLocationID] 
FROM Productlocation 
WHERE BillingLocationID = 1 AND DepartmentID = 3
```

Where C2, C3, etc the columns you want to copy.